# Save small data in play application

Tags: playframework

My problem is I want to save information about send mail: hostname, smtp port...
and only record, How to save them and don't use database, thanks for advance.

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't want to use a database, you  could save it in RAM but keep in mind that if you restart the server the data is gone.

You could save the data in the [cache](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache)

If the data is about users, you could save it in a [cookie](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaSessionFlash#Storing-data-into-the-Session).

Another option is a simple file.

You didn't ask for it but may I suggest, you just use some kind of file database ? 
Sqlite is probably a good fit.

Comment: Thanks for comment, I save them in database for simple.

Comment: @ChungDo Here is an example using sqlite http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/play-sqlite

Comment: Thank again. I will try.